# Get the value from the list with strings and numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers

Need to get nearest value

```
mylist=['A-B-10','A-B-20','A-B-50']

number=70

Output=A-B-50
```

Nearest two values

```
Output=A-B-50,A-B-20
```

tried with

```
min(range(len(mylist)), key = lambda i: abs(mylist[i]-number))
```

The list is string and it doesnt work. Any way to decode this and use on simple function.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does it do?

Comment: Bcz it works with integers, the value in list is string formatted with integer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get nearest value, you need to extract the integer value from the string:

```py
out = min(mylist, key=lambda i: abs(int(i.split("-")[-1]) - number))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
A-B-50
```

---

To get two nearest numbers:

```py
val1 = min(mylist, key=lambda i: abs(int(i.split("-")[-1]) - number))
mylist.remove(val1)
val2 = min(mylist, key=lambda i: abs(int(i.split("-")[-1]) - number))
print(val1, val2)
```

Prints:

```
A-B-50 A-B-20
```

Comment: How to get two nearest numbers

Comment: @MadanRaj See my edit